# Developing Android Exploits

Tags: exploit, android

I have some experience in exploiting. I participated at some CTFs and I have enough knowledge in Linux exploitation techniques. I know Arm and I know how heaps and stacks work.

My aim is to move on Android platform, but the first thing that blocked me is the Tool to use. On Linux with IDA I can make static analysis and with GDb I can make some debugs and check heap layout, stack layout, and register status in order to get a clear idea on how I am manipulating memory.

On Android there is the AOSP and I don't need something like IDA but how can I check the memory layout, registers, and so on (like GDB)? What approach should I use?

Comment: Can you program in C++? If you learn how to program in C, then you will learn how to manipulate memory

Comment: You didn't understand the Question.. I know Both and I know how to manipulate memory. I need to know how to use something like gdb for Android

Answer (score 3):

To check memory layout and so on you can always use gdb as you did before. For instance, push gdbserver on your device, use adb to forward tcp port used by gdbserver and then use gdb by your side... that's all.

I suppose you get android-sdk and ndk installed

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.. Do you have any reference link.. An example on how to debug a system service or something on android with GDB?